# Uploading images with redactor to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, image-uploading, redactor

This might be a bit too specific for here and I may need to contact redactor support but i've seen other questions about redactor here so i figured i'd give it a shot ...

Ok ...

So i'm trying to get get image uploading to work following the example here ...

http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/images/

My client side code ...

```
        $("textarea").redactor({
            focus: true,
            imageUpload: '/MyController/UploadImage'
        });
```

My MVC controller action looks like this ...

```
    public JsonResult UploadImage(object image)
    {
        // Do something with whatever that was i got from redactor
        var result = new { filelink = "" };
        return Json(result);
    }
```

The problem is ... what did redactor actually give me?
Was it the whole file? a chunk? i can't seem to tell because the object has no  type information at all and the raw post information seems way too little to actually be a whole image file.

Has anyone had any experience with this / actually done it before?
I don't really want to setup php on my server for this 1 function.

EDIT:
Ok a bit more digging reveals that if i pull the underlying Request object it has a files property which apparently contains my posted image file.
I think i might be able to figure it out from here.

Where I get a code block in place i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: You will probably find that `image` is of type `HttpPostedFileBase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok um ... i think im there ...
This needs a bit of cleaning up and I don't expect you guys to understand what goes on under the bonnet of my custom DMS code but just assume it takes the stream and returns a FileInfo object and in theory this should work for you too ...

```
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            // this object is specific to my system but all it does is 
            // stream the file to a path on the server (code not needed for this Q)
            var dmsService = _kernel.Get<IDMSFileSystemService>();

            List<FileInfo> savedFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                using (file.InputStream)
                {
                    savedFiles.Add(dmsService.AddFromStream(file.InputStream, file.FileName);
                }
            }
            var result = savedFiles.Select(f => new { filelink = f.Path}).ToArray();
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Suprisingly simple right ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a HttpPostedFileBase object. Here is my implementation:

jQuery:

```
$('#blog-post').redactor(
    {
    imageUpload: '/blog/images/',
    imageGetJson: '/images/locations/blogs/'
});
```

Then in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Images(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if( file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 )
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName( file.FileName );
            // store the file
            var path = Path.Combine( ImageLocation.BlogPicturePath, fileName );

            file.SaveAs( path );
        }
        return Json( new { filelink = ImageLocation.BlogPictureUrl + "/" + file.FileName } );
    }
```